# How can i get rid of this?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to do a car but i just cannot get this plane shape to get the exact form as the hood of the car.

And if anyone knows how to also stretch the bottom of the hood (where the headlights are) so it will match the photo that would be helpful too.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE, it's not clear what you're precisely asking, try to narrow down your question to a specific issue to get better answers, for instance, are you having problems moving the vertices? Or overlapping issues? Snapping? viewing your reference...etc.? If you have more than one issue, ask them in different questions, there could be already questions like yours that have answers already.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, you need more vertices.  The plane is getting twisted up.  It looks like you have something this:

[image]

You need to move those vertices back to where they should be:

[image]

Then subdivide the horizontal lines:

[image]
[image]

that will give you more horizontal vertices to follow the line of the hood:

[image]

To get the shape of the headlight area you'll likely need a lot more:

[image]

It is good to try to keep the number of vertices as low as possible, and let the subdivision modifier do the work, but you need at least something to work with.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This is what i needed.

Comment: @AlexandruBecheanu Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).